# Plot lm model/ multiple linear regression model using jtools

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, linear-regression, lm

I want to plot a regression line from an lm model with multiple predictors, which can be done with the function "effect_plot" from the package Jtools (plotting is done with ggplot2). Here is the documentation for jtools/effect_plot: [Documentation Jtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/jtools.pdf)

Here is an example:

```
library(datasets)
library(jtools)
model <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy, data = as.data.frame(state.x77))
summary(model)
effect_plot(model, pred = "Illiteracy")
```

I get the following:

> effect_plot(model, pred = "Illiteracy")
>   Error in effect_plot(model, pred = "Illiteracy") : 
>     could not find function "effect_plot"

ANY IDEA WHY EFFECT_PLOT DOES NOT WORK????

Within jtools there is another function called "interact_plot" for plotting interactions, which works fine:

```
model <- lm(Income ~ Illiteracy * Murder, data = as.data.frame(state.x77))
summary(model)
interact_plot(model, pred = "Illiteracy", modx = "Murder")
```

Here is the output: 
[Plot from interact_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jWJn.png)

Or any alternative idea? I know that there have been solutions, where the predicted values are saved in a vector and then plotted using ggplot (e.g.: [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615791/plot-regression-line-from-multiple-regression-in-r)) but it would be great if there is a way to generate a plot directly based on the lm object.

Thanks for any help!

Here are my session Infos:

R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/jtools.pdf) LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252

attached base packages:
[1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/jtools.pdf) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/jtools.pdf) jtools_0.4.4         RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/jtools.pdf) compiler_3.4.0   RevoUtils_10.0.4 tools_3.4.0

Comment: Did you forget a `library(jtools)` at the beginning of your script?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will add it to my example. But this is not the solution for the problem, as I have jtools loaded in my original script (accordingly, the interact_plot from jtools works just fine).

Comment: The script you gave works for me, can you please give us the result of a `sessionInfo()`? (Just to be clear: I can reproduce your exact error message if I forget to load the library)

Comment: That is weird. Sure, abover are the Infos. I have tried to restart/ load und unload jtools several times before posting the question. Also loading ggplot2 before running the function. Nothing worked. I am only able to plot with the second function (interact_plot).

Comment: Can you try `jtools::effect_plot(model, pred = "Illiteracy")` instead? I run your code on my machine and there was no error. I'm using jtools version 0.9.4 - is this what you're using as well?

Comment: Thanks for your help. jtools::effect_plot(model, pred = "Illiteracy") also returns an error message. I am using jtools version 0.4.4., which is the latest version I get (I just installed the package again). I tried to download the package directly from github (devtools::install_github("jacob-long/jtools"), but this did not work out (maybe because I do not habe admin rights on my computer). Any other idea how I can get jtools version 0.9.4?

Comment: Yes, you need to update R: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/R-3.5.0-win.exe

Comment: I looked for the function `effect_plot` in your version of `jtools` and could not find it. If you want to use it, you will need to update R and download `jtools` again.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I guess you two are right, that it has to do with the different versions of jtools. I will try to persuade our IT Departement to update R (I cannot download the version myself). This will take time....